How to implement commands working only in evil-snipe mode?
Good day,
I am using doom emacs on a new Mac OS. I want to implement some functions using evil-snipe and it's underlying navigation mechanism.
I implemented the following repeat function:
(evil-define-motion my/zap-repeat (arg)
  :type line
  "Paste a line below."
  (interactive "<R><x><c><y>")
...
...
)

It works well, but I don't know how to make it work only when in Snipe mode (entered by evil-snipe-f for example)
I used the following key definitions:
(evil-define-key 'motion evil-snipe-override-local-mode-map "$" 'my/zap-repeat)
(evil-define-key 'motion evil-snipe-override-mode-map "$" 'my/zap-repeat)
(evil-define-key 'normal evil-snipe-parent-transient-map "$" 'my/zap-repeat)

This one seems to make it work, but globally, not only in Snipe mode as I want it:
(evil-define-key 'normal evil-snipe-local-mode-map "$" 'my/zap-repeat)

How can I make this function respond only in snipe mode?
